# How to change iframe height in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a js/jquery code as shown below in which I want to override  the css present in the **HTML Code** below.

```js
console.log("iframe height is", $("div.scribble-live").find("iframe").css("height"));
$("div.scribble-live").find("iframe").css("height", "200px");
console.log("iframe height is", $("div.scribble-live").find("iframe").css("height"));
```

```css
.scribble-live, .scrbbl-embed {
  border: thin black solid;
  margin: 1em;
}

iframe {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scribble-live">
       <div class="scrbbl-embed">
         <iframe width="100%" height="15236px" frameborder="0"
           class="scrbbl-embed scrbbl-event"
           style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 50px; height: 15236px; min-width: 100%;">
         </iframe>
       </div>
</div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

The above js/jquery code doesn't seem to override the css ( `style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 50px; height: 15236px; min-width: 100%;"`) present in the HTML code above.

Comment: I made your code runnable to help a little with diagnosing your problem and added a couple of log statements.  You'll note that the CSS attribute *does* change with your code.  Odds are you're looking for a visible change in the *layout* as a result of the CSS change.  However, to test that, we need more example HTML so we can see how the <iframe> is supposed to interact with surrounding elements.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are 2 different things what you need to do here because there are 2 places where you have height values in your generated HTML code. Because you cannot remove any of them as I understand we need to operate with these steps:

**1. Attribute change**

The first thing is to change the height attribute from your code with the following line of code:

```
$("div.scribble-live").find("iframe").attr("height", "200px");
```

This will change the height attribute in the following HTML as below:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="200px" frameborder="0"
       class="scrbbl-embed scrbbl-event"
       style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 50px; height: 15236px; min-width: 100%;">
 </iframe>
```

You can read further about [.attr() here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

**2. Style property change**

The second thing which is changing the style attribute's height value:

```
$("div.scribble-live").find("iframe").css("height", "200px");
```

By doing this the second height in the style attribute will be changed as well:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="200px" frameborder="0"
       class="scrbbl-embed scrbbl-event"
       style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 50px; height: 200px; min-width: 100%;">
     </iframe>
```

Read more about jQuery function [.css() here](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

**Summary**

With those function calls you are changing both values. Let me share a picture which function is changing what:
[image: Attr-css]

**Update:**
Just realized that you have the height 2 times in your HTML so I have updated my answer based on that.

Comment: Just edited my answer, you have the height property 2 times in your code.

Comment: Do I need to paste this `$("div.scribble-live").find("iframe").attr("height", "200px");` only in my script ?

Comment: I guess if you use your original solution with the css function and just remove the height attribute from the iframe html tag (not from style) then it will work. The issue is that you have the height as attribute and also as a style property. So if you keep the height only in style attribute and using the jQuery's css function then it should work. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: html code is not in my control because it is created through script.

Comment: In this case you need to add as an extra operation next to the css function the following (css will handle the style attribute and attr will deal with the height attribute): $("div.scribble-live").find("iframe").attr("height", "200px");

Comment: I am wondering if you can modified in your answer **what I need to add** because comments can be confusing.

Comment: Just updated with the final solution which might work. Let me know if you face still an issue.

Comment: Please consider accepting this one as an answer if the solution is working for you, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For **override** the `height prop` in style attribute.

```
$("div.scribble-live .scrbbl-event").height("200px");
```

For **override** the iframe `height` attribute.

```
$("div.scribble-live .scrbbl-event").attr("height", "200px");
```

You have to execute both script because `height prop` inside `style attribute` will always override the iframe height attibute value.