# change iframe width/height in js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

I am working on a js/jquery code in which I want to override current css present in the html code below.

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
<script>
       $("div.scribble-live").find("iframe").css("height", "200 px");
</script>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="scribble-live">
   <div class="scrbbl-embed">
      <iframe name="ee5bdd02" width="100%" height="15299px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" title="scrbbl:event ScribbleLive Embed" src="" class="scrbbl-embed scrbbl-event" style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 50px; height: 15299px; min-width: 100%;"></iframe>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

The above js/jquery code doesn't seem to override the css ( `style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 50px; height: 15236px; min-width: 100%;"`) present in the HTML code above.

I tried with the following scripts as well but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<script>
$("div.scribble-live").find("iframe").attr("height", "200px");
</script>

<script>
$("div.scribble-live").find("iframe").attr("height", "200px");
$("div.scribble-live .scrbbl-event").height("200px"); 
</script>
```

Comment: possible typeo? `200px` not `200 px`

Comment: It didn't work still

Comment: Works just fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/9wfLah1j/

Comment: `$("div.scribble-live").find("iframe").css("height", "200px");`

Comment: @adeneo In my codebase `display:none` seems to work but I don't know why `height:200px` is not working

Comment: Did you try the line above, with `css()` ?

Comment: yes, I copied the same line.

Comment: @adeneo I have updated my html code. Also, html code is generated at run time through script.

Comment: What do you mean by "run time"? If it's generated with javascript you might have to wrap a "setTimeout" around the code that changes the styles.

Comment: @adeneo  this works `$("div.scribble-live").find("iframe").css("display", "none");` but not `$("div.scribble-live").find("iframe").css("height", "200px");`

Comment: Then you probably have overriding styles, maybe something that is `!important` ?

Comment: Yes, it is generated through javascript. can you let me know in an answer what I need to do ?

Comment: No, I don't have overriding styles.

Comment: I have no idea what you need to do, the line above works for me, so you have to figure out why it doesn't work for you ?

Comment: You can add a delay like this, to see if that helps -> https://jsfiddle.net/74hg8txL/1/

Comment: Duplicate of your own previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55406588/

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to work. Might consider using `.ready()` callback on the `iframe` or use `setTimeout()` to wait before making the change.

```js
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".scrbbl-event").css("height", "200px");
  }, 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scribble-live">
  <div class="scrbbl-embed">
    <iframe name="ee5bdd02" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" title="scrbbl:event ScribbleLive Embed" src="" class="scrbbl-embed scrbbl-event" style="background: #ccc; border: none; width: 50px; height: 15299px; min-width: 100%;"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.